# How to add Ticker column to Quandl API call?

Tags: equities, csv, quandl

I was curious how I would get this same data, but also with a column with a  ticker column (e.g. FB)?

[image: OutputSample]

https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB/data.csv?&start_date=2014-01-01&end_date=2014-12-31&api_key=mykey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution - You must have ticker list. And you can use "paste" function from R(or concatenation function from the respective software) to do it. Following is the example,

*ticker = c("FB","APPL")

i = 1

Link = paste(paste("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/", ticker[i], sep = ""), 
            "/data.csv?&start_date=2014-01-01&end_date=2014-12-31&api_key=mykey",sep = "")*

You can generalize it with "for" loop for as many tickers as you want.